# QUERIES RELATED TO ORACLE METADATA

Tags: oracle

Can anyone help me in finding some data related to Oracle Metadata .

I have certain very specific questions around it . Listing them below as per my understanding :

- Where can i get **Table** metadata details like Table Size, create timestamp and update timestamp for all the tables
- Where can i get **View** metadata details like create timestamp and update timestamp for all the Views in the database
- Where can i get **Procedure** metadata details like content of procedure create timestamp and update timestamp for all the Procedures in the database
- Where can i get  **Column** metadata details like create timestamp and update timestamp for all the Columns in all the tables in the database
- Where can i get **MACRO** metadata details like content of MACRO create timestamp and update timestamp for all the Procedures in the database
- Where can i get Data regarding metadata of **Queries** like Runtime, IO Time , CPU Time etc
- Where can i get **INDEX** metadata details

Comment: Please consider reading [ask]. Questions that show no previous research and are too broad may not be well received here (or anywhere else).

Comment: I reccomend that you start with the "Oracle Concepts Guide".

Answer (score 0):

When you aren't sure where to look at, check the **dictionary**. For example:

```
SQL> select * From dictionary where lower(comments) like '%procedure%';

TABLE_NAME           COMMENTS
-------------------- -------------------------------------------------------
ALL_PROCEDURES       Functions/procedures/packages/types/triggers available
                     to the user

USER_AUDIT_OBJECT    Audit trail records for statements concerning objects,
                     specifically: table, cluster, view, index, sequence,  [
                     public] database link, [public] synonym, procedure, tri
                     gger, rollback segment, tablespace, role, user

USER_PROCEDURES      Description of the user functions/procedures/packages/t
                     ypes/triggers


SQL>
```

Even if it doesn't return *exactly* what you need, that can be a starting point. Note that some searches might return a lot of results (for example, if the search term is "table", my 11g XE returns 164 rows so - you might need to apply additional condition(s)).

Comment: Note that this only returns something in the `comments` column for the SYS or SYSTEM users. It seems regular users (even with `select_catalog_role`) can't see those comments

Comment: I've just tried it, @a_horse, connected as *dummy* users SCOTT (whose cat was Tiger), MIKE (I use for testing purposes), a *regular* user which was granted only necessary privileges ... works the same for all of them (on 11gR2). Tried on one of users on 12cR2 - no difference. None of them was SYS nor SYSTEM (I don't have privileges to connect as those users anyway).

Comment: Interesting. I tried it with 12.2 and 18c and did not see any comments as a regular user (`where comments is not null` returned exactly one row). This can also be seen on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4cca16cd3e13ee610dd31ccc74891943). Maybe there is an additional installation step to be done so that the view is populated.

Comment: Huh, I don't think so. My message was posted yesterday evening (CET); query I ran was executed on my home 11gXE and I certainly didn't install any additions (you know how it goes - run setup and click NEXT several times and here you are, XE is ready for you).